# best way for convert binary list to list of chars (of two special char)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

i have a special list like this:

```
[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1]
```

I want it map to a char list like:

```
['+','+','+','-','+','-','+','-','-','-','+','-']
```

here is some code. it multiplies probabilities to calculate joint probabilities:

```
def solve_all_asigned(self,joint_s):
    mult_val=1
    for tab in self.tables:
        if tab['decision']:
            continue
        name=tab['name']
        nr=name.replace('.',' ')
        nr_spd=re.split(' ',nr)
        val=''
        check_list=[x in joint_s.keys() for x in nr_spd]
        if False in check_list:
            continue
        val=''.join(map(joint_s.get,nr_spd))
        mult_val=mult_val*tab[val]
    return mult_val

n=22
joint_s2={}
all_combinations=list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat=n))
for binlist in all_combinations:
    for i in range(n):
        joint_s2[nan_set[i]]='+' if binlist[i]=='0' else '-'
    s.append(self.solve_all_asigned(joint_s2))
ss=sum(s)

joint_s:{'AA': 'nan', 'AC': 'nan', 'AB': 'nan', 'AE': 'nan', 'AD': 'nan', 'AF': 'nan', 'A': 'nan', 'C': 'nan', 'B': 'nan', 'E': 'nan', 'D': 'nan', 'G': 'nan', 'F': 'nan', 'I': 'nan', 'H': 'nan', 'K': 'nan', 'J': 'nan', 'M': 'nan', 'L': 'nan', 'O': 'nan', 'N': 'nan', 'Q': 'nan', 'P': '+', 'S': 'nan', 'R': 'nan', 'U': 'nan', 'T': 'nan', 'W': 'nan', 'V': 'nan', 'Y': 'nan', 'X': '+', 'Z': 'nan'}
nan_set:['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'G', 'F', 'I', 'H', 'K', 'J', 'M', 'L', 'O', 'N', 'Q', 'S', 'R', 'U', 'T', 'W', 'V']
tab:{'name': 'A.B', '--': 0.19999999999999996, 'decision': False, '+-': 0.6, '++': 0.4, '-+': 0.8}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code so far?

Comment: I try to calculate joint and conditional probabilities. '+' means that I should calculate p(x) and '-' for 1-p(x)

Comment: @elahe: the question is not what the aim is of the project, but more what you tried to do to solve the problem in the question statement yourself.

Comment: That is not what I asked. How have you tried to solve this particular problem? Also, do you really want to use the `map` function, or would a list comprehension or a `for` loop suffice?

Comment: What Rory & Willem said. We'd like to see the code that you've tried to write which is supposed to convert `[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1]` to `['+','+','+','-','+','-','+','-','-','-','+','-']`

Comment: However, I suspect we have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. You really don't need a list of `'+'` and `'-'` for those probability calculations.

Comment: @ Rory Daulton . it is not important what I use but it must be sufficient because I maight have more that 20 variables!

Comment: is there a better way to do this? unfortunately my program is very slow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your original question, here's an efficient way to map a list of 0 & 1 integers to plus and minus signs.

```
binlist = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
a = ['+-'[u] for u in binlist]
print(a)
```

**output**

```
['+', '+', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '-', '-', '+', '-']
```

---

However, as I said above, this *may* not actually be necessary for your probability calculations.

Here are some other improvements that can be made to your code.

```
all_combinations=list(itertools.product([0,1],repeat=n))
for binlist in all_combinations:
```

wastes a *lot* of RAM. For `n = 22`, the `all_combinations` list contains over 4 million 22 item tuples. It's far more efficient to iterate over the output of `product` directly:

```
for binlist in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n):
```

In this line:

```
joint_s2[nan_set[i]]='+' if binlist[i]=='0' else '-'
```

You test `binlist[i]` against the *string* `'0'`, but the `binlist` tuples contain the *integers* 0 and 1, not strings, and Python will not automatically convert numeric strings to integers or vice versa.

Another puzzling section is

```
nr=name.replace('.',' ')
nr_spd=re.split(' ',nr)
```

Why use regex? Why not just use the built-in `str.split` method, eg

```
nr_spd = name.split('.')
```

OTOH, if your `name` fields may be separated by one or more spaces as well as by at most a single dot then you can do

```
nr_spd = name.replace('.', ' ', 1).split()
```

Comment: .thank you for your answer. 'tab' is a dictionary that contains probablilities. 'nan_set' is a list of all variable and 'joint_s' is joint statement. I'll edit my question and add them.

Comment: for example: A B C D.E

Comment: is there a better way to do this? unfortunately my program is very slow...

Comment: Maybe, but you _are_ processing a lot of combinations. Maybe you should ask a new question, and try to explain a bit more about what you're doing. You can link back to this question in your new one, and let people know that it's a follow-up question.